# Mark & Clear sharp

Tags: mesh, edges

I have just started with Blender. What is the this tool *Mark & clear Sharp* and what is its use?

Comment: Thanks for helping me، I love a blender but I can write a little English and i from iran thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two features are used in Shade Smooth to manually control which edges you want them to be absolute sharp. The auto smooth should be open.